# undefined local variable or method `asistencia_params' for #<AsistenciaController:0x00000000083450>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, compiler-errors

```
class AsistenciaController < ApplicationController
  def asistencia
    @username = params[:user_username]
    @entry = params[:user_entry]
    if @asistencia.update(asistencia_params)
      redirect_to asistencia_path, notice: "Asistencia Guardada"
    else 
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end

undefined local variable or method `asistencia_params' for #<AsistenciaController:0x00000000083450>
```

I expected to be able to update the entry with the use of the name

I want to emphasize that in other controllers all the usernames, entries are already defined.

Comment: you need to define the `asistencia_params` method yourself. It's idiomatic rails controller syntax for invoking "strong parameters" protection and sanitization of the parameters hash. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: In the other controller see where the params are defined.  That is what you need to add in this controller, Likely in the bottom of the file under the keyword `private` (but maybe not if these are custom built files).  There will be somethng like `def user_params` that is what this controller needs, the values you whitelist will be specific to this object, and so will the name of the params like the comment above mentions.

Comment: You can get an example of this straight from rails itself.  Try (on a clean branch) `bundle exec rails g scaffold Post title:string body:string`.  It'll generate a `posts_controller.rb`, at the bottom you'll find a `#post_params` method with: `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)`. You want to add a similar method that applies to the acceptable params for your form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the method asistencia_params like this in your controller.

```
def asistencia_params
  #here you can permit or do whatever you want
  (eg params assignment or permiting only required params for processing)
  params.require(:asistencia).permit(:user_name, :user_entry, etc..)

end
```